# Transaction rollback not working when rollback is done on MySql db

Tags: java, mysql, transactions

I have implemented transactional rollback in the following way. This code worked well when I tried to implement the same on HSql DB and SQL Server. But the same transactional rollback is not working when implemented on MySQL DB. What could be the possible solution for rolling back the transaction in case of MySQL?

Here is my code -

xml file-> implement.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd ">

   <!-- Initialization for data source -->
   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://(mydb details)"/>
      <property name="username" value="(my db username)"/>
      <property name="password" value="(my db password)"/>
   </bean>


   <!-- Initialization for TransactionManager -->
   <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
      <property name="dataSource"  ref="dataSource" />    
   </bean>

   <!-- Definition for studentJDBCTemplate bean -->
   <bean id="implementOnlyTransactions" class="Transactions.implementOnlyTransactions">
      <property name="dataSource"  ref="dataSource" />
      <property name="transactionManager"  ref="transactionManager" />    
   </bean>

</beans>
```

implementOnlyTransactions.java->

```
package Transactions;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionDefinition;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionException;
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionStatus;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.DefaultTransactionDefinition;


public class implementOnlyTransactions {
    private DataSource dataSource;
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateObject;
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) throws SQLException {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.jdbcTemplateObject = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    public void setTransactionManager(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        this.transactionManager = transactionManager;
    }

    public void create(Integer id, String name) throws Exception {
        TransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
        TransactionStatus status = transactionManager.getTransaction(def);

        try {
            String SQL1 = "insert into Student (ID,Name) values (?, ?)";
            int r = jdbcTemplateObject.update(SQL1, id, name);
            System.out.println("Inserted Name = " + name + ", ID = " + id);
            if(r>0){
                transactionManager.rollback(status);
            }
             transactionManager.commit(status);

        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            System.out.println("Error in creating record, rolling back");
            //transactionManager.rollback(status);
            throw e;
        }

    }

}
```

MainClass.java -->

```
package Transactions;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("xmlFiles/implement.xml");

        implementOnlyTransactions implemt = 
                (implementOnlyTransactions)context.getBean("implementOnlyTransactions");

        try {
            implemt.create(36,"bye2");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you use InnoDB, or MyISAM? Because MyISAM doesn't support transactions.

Comment: InnoDB is enabled!